# Get subnet id's from map(object(map(object(set(string)))) variable parameter - terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy an azure keyvault with some network_acls rules as well, in an as modular as possible way:

This is a variable I have in my main variable file:

```
variable "keyvault" {
  type = object({
    sku                             = string
    enabled_for_deployment          = bool
    enabled_for_disk_encryption     = bool
    enabled_for_template_deployment = bool
    purge_protection_enabled        = string
    soft_delete_retention_days      = string
    rbac_authorization_enabled      = bool
    public_network_access_enabled   = bool
    net_rules = map(object({
      default_action               = string
      bypass                       = string
      ip_rules                     = string
      virtual_network_subnet_names = set(string)
    }))
    resource_group_name = string
  })
}
```

You can see I'm having the subnet names in there, as for me, that's general in modular, more than enterring the subnet id's in there, hardcoded.
Then, I've got a keyvault module, which receives this parameters like this:

```
  net_rules = var.keyvault.net_rules
```

I'm trying to deploy the keyvault with the rules, there can be multiple rules, and each rule can have multiple subnet id's. These are put in a set of strings, and this part of the code, in the keyvault module looks like this:

```
  dynamic "network_acls" {
    for_each = var.net_rules
    content {
      default_action             = each.default_action
      bypass                     = each.bypass
      ip_rules                   = each.ip_rules
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = local.subnet_ids_by_rule[each.key]
    }
  }
```

I'm using a local variable, in combination with a data block, to be able to convert the subnet names into a set of subnet id's, one set per network rule.
This part is done by this code:

```
locals {
  subnet_ids_by_rule = {
    for rule, rule_config in var.keyvault.net_rules : rule => [
      for subnet in data.azurerm_subnet.selected_subnets : subnet.id
      if subnet.name in rule_config.subnet_names
    ]
  }
}
```

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "selected_subnets" {
  count = length([for net_rule in var.keyvault.net_rules : net_rule]) # Count based on the number of rules

  name                 = [for rule in var.keyvault.net_rules : rule.key][count.index]
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
}
```

The part in the main of the module does look quite logic to me, but the data and locals parts are a bit more difficult to me, at the moment, this is not working, but I'm not sure I'm attacking these in the best way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to create multiple network_acls, it's a dynamic but can max be 1 so in actuality it's more like an optional block.

> network_acls - (Optional) A network_acls block as defined below.

[Key Vault documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault#argument-reference)

If you change net_rules to an optional object you should be able to do this instead

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "selected_subnets" {
  for_each = var.keyvault.net_rules == null ? {} : var.keyvault.net_rules.virtual_network_subnet_names

  name                 = each.key
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
}
```

And then

```
dynamic "network_acls" {
    for_each = var.keyvault.net_rules == null ? {} : var.keyvault.net_rules
    content {
      default_action             = each.value.default_action
      bypass                     = each.value.bypass
      ip_rules                   = each.value.ip_rules
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = [ for subnet_key, subnet_value in data.azurerm_subnet.selected_subnet : subnet_value.id ]
    }
  }
```

Making the object optional means that you must handle null cases, but with the benefit of not requiring an empty map if not set.

EDIT: I would not recommend it, but here is one way to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
locals {
  merge = merge([ 
    # Create a list of all the rules
    for rule_key, rule_value in var.keyvault.net_rules :  {
      for subnet in rule_value.virtual_network_subnet_names :
        # Construct a key from rule name + subnet name and map it to the subnet name
        "${rule_key}-${subnet}" => subnet
    }
  # Expand the list (basically removes the list so our maps are passed as arguments to merge)
  ]...)
}

#  Now we should have a list that looks like
#  merge = {
#    "rule1-sub1" = "sub1"
#    "rule1-sub2" = "sub2"
#    "rule2-sub3" = "sub3"
#    "rule3-sub4" = "sub4"
#  }

data "azurerm_subnet" "selected_subnets" {
  # Import all subnets, using the rule+subnet as identifier
  for_each = local.merge

  name                 = each.value
  # Keep in mind that you only do this for one virtual network
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
}
```

And in keyvault

```
  dynamic "network_acls" {
    # Now construct the the block per rule
    for_each = var.keyvault.net_rules
    content {
      default_action             = each.value.default_action
      bypass                     = each.value.bypass
      ip_rules                   = each.value.ip_rules
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = [ 
        # Iterate over each subnet in the rule
        for subnet in each.value.virtual_network_subnet_names :
          # Now can simply pick out each element by combining rule and subnet name
          data.azurerm_subnet.selected_subnet["${each.key}-${subnet}"]
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to try this shortly, thanks for the elaborate answer!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any clearifications regarding my answer.